# Rundeck inline bash spinner output

Tags: bash, rundeck

Have some bash test code that have a spinner. Code seems like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5 &
pid=$!
frames="/ | \\ -"
while kill -0 $pid 2&>1 > /dev/null;
do
    for frame in $frames;
    do
        printf "\r$frame Loading..." 
        sleep 0.5
    done
done
printf "\n"
```

This code is write on a inline step.

The problem is, in output screen, spinner shows like this

```
/ Loading...| Loading...\ Loading...- Loading.../ Loading...| Loading...\ Loading...- Loading.../ Loading...| Loading...\ Loading...- Loading...
```

Anybody knows how to handle this situation in rundeck?

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` instead of `printf` (take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYg2x.jpg)), but even using `echo` Rundeck output doesn't work as an interactive terminal, which means that you can't see the bar "spinning".

Each update is printed as a new line/string. The best way is to see a "loading" effect is using  an "update line", e.g:

```sh
x=1
echo "starting..."
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
  sleep 2
  echo "***"
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
echo "done!"
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXRtU.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what "Rundeck" is or what your kill line is trying to do but in terms of implementing a spinner in bash, this works perfectly for me:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

frames=( '\\' '|' '/' '-' )
cnt=0
while (( ++cnt < 10 ))
do
    for frame in "${frames[@]}"
    do
        printf "\r$frame Loading..."
        sleep 0.5
    done
done
printf "\n"
```

There's no way to see it spinning here of course but FWIW:

```
$ ./tst.sh
/ Loading...
```